# Not able to update password in database using phpmailer

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to develop forgot password system. Everything seems to work fine, even password updated message prompts on my login screen page, but in reality its not been updated in database. I couldn't understand why this is happening. Also I am using phpmailer for sending email's. Any help will be of great help

Reset password page:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['reset-submit'])){

    $selector=$_POST['selector'];
    $validator=$_POST['validator'];
    $password=$_POST['password1'];
    $passwordRepeat=$_POST['password2'];

    if(empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)){
        echo "empty fields";
    }
    elseif($password!=$passwordRepeat){
        echo "password did not match";
    }

    $expiryDate=date("U");
    require "db.inc.php";

    $sql="SELECT * FROM pwdreset WHERE pwdresetSelector=? AND pwdresetExpires >= ?;";
    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
        echo "Could not validate your request";
    }
    else{
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$selector,$expiryDate);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if(!$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "Could not validate your request";
        }
        else{
            $tokenBin=hex2bin($validator);
            $tokenCheck=password_verify($tokenBin,$row['pwdresetToken']);

            if($tokenCheck===false){
                echo "Could not validate your request";
            }
            elseif($tokenCheck===true){
                $tokenEmail=$row['pwdresetEmail'];

                $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailUsers=?;";
                $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
                    echo "Could not validate your request";
                }
                else{
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$tokenEmail);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                    if(!$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "Could not validate your request";
                    }
                    else{
                        $sql="UPDATE users SET pwdUsers=? WHERE emailUsers=?;";
                        $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
                            echo "Could not validate your request";
                        }
                        else{
                            $newpasswordHash=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$tokenEmail,$newpasswordHash);
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                            $sql="DELETE FROM pwdreset WHERE pwdresetEmail=?;";
                            $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
                                header("Location: ../createnewpassword.php?error=sqlerror");
                                exit();
                            }
                            else{
                                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$tokenEmail);
                                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                                header("Location: ../login.php?resetpassword=success");
                                exit();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "Could not validate your request";
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
 }
 else{
     header("Location: ../index.php");
     exit();
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to be unkind, and I do realize everyone has to start somewhere, but this looks to me like [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). I would build in more echo's, especially one that says that your update is being executed. If you don't see that message the error is somewhere in the code before that, and more echo's are needed to find out where this code veers off course.

Comment: I've noticed that you only use `mysqli_stmt_close()` once, whereas you use a lot of `mysqli_stmt_init()` and `mysqli_stmt_prepare()`. I would use `mysqli_stmt_close()` more consistently, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was hard to read with so many else statements and generic messages. When developing you want to display errors that are easy for you to 1. understand what caused them and 2. handle them appropriately. These messages should only be generic (no mysql errors etc) when the code is in production.

I put your code into a function and to make it a lot easy to handle and read.

I assume your problem came down to this line:
`mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$newpasswordHash,$tokenEmail);`
Where you had reversed the values for the Update. If I was making this for myself to use I'd probably just use a class and break it up into different functions as it's quite a big piece of code doing multiple functions.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['reset-submit'])){

    $selector=$_POST['selector'];
    $validator=$_POST['validator'];
    $password=$_POST['password1'];
    $passwordRepeat=$_POST['password2'];

    if(empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)){
        echo "empty fields";
        exit();
    }
    elseif($password!=$passwordRepeat){
        echo "password did not match";
        exit();
    }

    $expiryDate=date("U");
    require "db.inc.php";

    $reset = reset_password( $conn , $selector , $validator , $password );
    if( ! $reset['Results'] ){

        echo $reset['Msg'];
        exit();

    }
    header("Location: ../login.php?resetpassword=success");
    exit();

}
else{
     header("Location: ../index.php");
     exit();
}

function reset_password( $conn , $selector , $validator , $password ){

    $sql="SELECT * FROM pwdreset WHERE pwdresetSelector=? AND pwdresetExpires >= ?;";
    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return [ 'Result' => false , 'Msg' => '1: SQL Error - ' . mysqli_error($conn) ];
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$selector,$expiryDate);

    if( ! mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ){
        return [ 'Result' => false , 'Msg' => 'Failed to execute 1' ];
    }
    $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if(!$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return [ 'Result' => false , 'Msg' => 'Failed to find reset' ];
    }

    $tokenBin=hex2bin($validator);
    if( ! password_verify($tokenBin,$row['pwdresetToken']) ){ //you can check against this directly. No need to put it into a variable.
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return [ 'Result' => false , 'Msg' => 'Incorrect Password' ];
    }
    $tokenEmail=$row['pwdresetEmail'];
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailUsers=?;";
    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return [ 'Result' => false , 'Msg' => '2: SQL Error - ' . mysqli_error($conn) ];
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$tokenEmail);
    if( ! mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ){
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return [ 'Result' => false , 'Msg' => 'Failed to execute 2' ];
    }
    $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if(!$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return [ 'Result' => false , 'Msg' => 'No User Found' ];
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    $sql="UPDATE users SET pwdUsers=? WHERE emailUsers=?;";
    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return [ 'Result' => false , 'Msg' => '3: SQL Error - ' . mysqli_error($conn) ];
    }

    $newpasswordHash=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$newpasswordHash,$tokenEmail); //you had these reversed. According to your SQL looks like it should be this way
    if( ! mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ){
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return [ 'Result' => false , 'Msg' => 'Failed to execute 3' ];
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    $sql="DELETE FROM pwdreset WHERE pwdresetEmail=?;";
    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return [ 'Result' => false , 'Msg' => '4: SQL Error - ' . mysqli_error($conn) ];
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$tokenEmail);
    if( ! mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ){
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        return [ 'Result' => false , 'Msg' => 'Failed to execute 4' ];
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    return [ 'Result' => true , 'Msg' => 'Failed to execute 4' ];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment I did reverse $newpasswordHash and $tokenEmail and I did pasted your code but it returned  'Failed to find reset'.

Comment: Then that points you in the direction you need to look. You probably meant to do `pwdresetExpires <= ?` if smaller than, but hard to tell without knowing the values and why you are testing it.